# Vuejs 3 how to get component instance properties programmatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

I have function which is written in vue 2 and I need to modifiy for vue 3. there is component named Modal which is a confirmation box with lots of props and option. in codebase it call showPrompt function programmatically many place and it basicly creates a new component instance and adds listeners for emits with $on method and mutates isVisible data to true to show component. Vue.component is changed with app.component and it's not returns registered component instance. and I cannot use $on, $destroy methods etc. how can i modifiy this function for version 3.

```
import Modal from '@/layouts/Modal.vue'

export function showPrompt (props: object) {
  const Klass = Vue.component('promptModal', Modal)
  const propsData = {
    positiveButtonColor: 'error',
    showPositiveButton: true,
    contentSlotPaddingClass: 'pa-0',
    ...props
  }
  // FIXME: Type Issue
  // @ts-ignore
  if (get(propsData, 'positiveButtonText', '') === 'Yes') {
    set(propsData, 'positiveButtonColor', 'primary')
  }
  const instance = new Klass({
    vuetify,
    i18n,
    propsData: propsData
  })
  each(get(propsData, 'listeners'), (listener, key) => {
    // FIXME: Type Issue
    // @ts-ignore
    instance.$on(key, listener)
  })
  instance.$on('dialogObserverCallback', (value: boolean) => {
    if (!value) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        instance.$destroy()
      }, 1000)
    }
  })
  instance.$mount()
  set(instance, 'isVisible', true)
  return instance
}
```

I tried defineExpose to access component data but couldn't make progres

Comment: There isn't supposed to be more than 1 instance at time, is it? A more viable approach would be to mount one component instance in the root, probably with <teleport> and interact with its ref through showPrompt. You don't have $on in Vue 3 and would need to add third-party event bus, for starters.

Comment: @EstusFlask if I use modal component with teleport with calling inside app.vue how can i pass props to my modal component?

Comment: It's <MyModal v-bind="modalGlobalStore.props"> in App.vue, then you assign it to what you receive in showPrompt params on call. Works best with global state because otherwise you'd be limited in the ways how you can use showPrompt

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of VueJS internals I believe - and also not a great way to engineer something like multiple components.

---

What you're looking to replace requires decent knowledge of how VueJS 3 works. The following is an example of *how* it works, but note that the component context (stores, plugins, directives...) will be lost:

```js
import { defineComponent, createApp } from 'vue';
import Modal from '@/layouts/Modal.vue';

const modalView = defineComponent({
    extends: Modal
})

const div = document.createElement('div');
this.$refs.container.appendChild(div);
createApp(modalView).mount(div)
```